# show that the bifurcation occur at an exact point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I'm having trouble with this problem. I have everything completed, but not the parte where I have to show that the saddle node bifurcation occur at k= -a + 1/2(a)^(1/2) and  k= -a - 1/2(a)^(1/2). I don't know how to do that. I'll be so thankfully is somebody can help me with it.  see document attached.[image]

Comment: yes! the book said is there

Comment: @amzoti the book saids is there but i don't know how to show it

Comment: is strogatz second edition. problem 8.1.11

Comment: @Amzoti is strogatz second edition. problem 8.1.11 I think the first edition is the same